# installation failed HAXM in android studio Lenovo

Tags: android, reactjs, installation, native, haxm

```
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Intel® HAXM installer
'C:\Users\Muhammad' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the batch label specified - in_exit9009
Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows
Done
```

i tried to enable virtualization both in bios
and using Windows features  turn on or off
i checked boxes Hyper V
and virtualization
but nothing happened

Comment: thanks mate its working Fine 
i just ignored everything and now emulator is running

Answer (score 0):

Intel has retired HAXM project in January 2023:

> HAXM was created to bring Intel Virtualization Technology to Windows and macOS users. Today both Microsoft Hyper-V and macOS HVF have added support for Intel Virtual Machine Extensions. We have therefore decided to retire the HAXM project. HAXM v7.8.0 is our last release and we will not accept pull requests or respond to issues after this. [<sup>1</sup>](https://github.com/intel/haxm#status)

HAXM was an optional software which enhanced the speed of Android x86 emulators (and other emulators). On Windows 10/11 HAXM can not work if Hyper-V is active. Therefore it can not be used anymore on most Windows systems.

And on modern MacOS systems which base on Apple M1/M2 chips HAXM will not work by design as it only works on 64bit x86 Intel CPUs.

As you can see from the Intel quote, HAXM is no longer required, so don't try to install it anymore. Just use Android emulator without.