# how to resolve the Intel HAXM installation failed

Tags: java, android

this is what my android studio stating. I resolve this issue a month by going to BIOS and activating the virtualization and checking the hyper v and such in the programs. And yet I opened my android studio today, and it shows this. How to resolve this? even though I activated a month a go the virtualization in the BIOS and HyperV

How to resolve this? even though I activated a month a go the virtualization in the BIOS and HyperV

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install intel HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418450/i-cant-install-intel-haxm)

Comment: Haxm is outdated and deprecated see my answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77261149/150978